# LoaderManager in Widget?

Tags: android, android-widget

I am really new to android widgets.

I have implemented a simple application with a widget. The application only saves notes to a ORMLite Database. Now I am trying to load stored notes for the widget via a LoaderManager.

The Andorid docu tells that there is a Fragment or an Activity needed, so my question is, is there any way to load something via a LoaderManager in a widget?

Answer (score 1):

No. The right approach is to use a Service with your AppWidget, and then work with your Loader directly in the Service.

Here is a discussion on how to do this:
[Can you use a LoaderManager from a Service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8696146/can-you-use-a-loadermanager-from-a-service)