# Using ContentProvider from an IntentService

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-broadcast, android-intentservice

I'm having problems using a ContentProvider from an IntentService.

I plan to use an IntentService in my app to reschedule some alarms when the phone finishes booting up, but first I need to pull some data from the ContentProvider. According to [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8696146/can-you-use-a-loadermanager-from-a-service) [links](http://dhimitraq.wordpress.com/2012/11/27/using-intentservice-with-alarmmanager-to-schedule-alarms/), I'd be able to that by registering a BroadcastReceiver and firing up the IntentService from there. That's what I did:

OnBootReceiver.java

```
public class OnBootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Intent scheduleServiceIntent = new Intent(context, ScheduleService.class);
    context.startService(scheduleServiceIntent);
}
```

ScheduleService.java

```
public class ScheduleService extends IntentService implements Loader.OnLoadCompleteListener<Cursor> {

private AlarmManager alarmManager;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    alarmManager = (AlarmManager) this.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    String[] projection = new String[] {
    Contract._ID,
            Contract.START_TIME,
    Contract.DATE,
            Contract.NAME,
            Contract.TYPE};

    mCursorLoader = new CursorLoader(this, MyContentProvider.MyURI,
            projection, selection, selectionArgs, SOME_ID);
    mCursorLoader.registerListener(ID, this);
    mCursorLoader.startLoading();
}

@Override
public void onLoadComplete(Loader<Cursor> cursorLoader, Cursor cursor) {

    //pull data from the Cursor and set the alarms
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

    if (mCursorLoader != null) {
        mCursorLoader.unregisterListener(this);
        mCursorLoader.cancelLoad();
        mCursorLoader.stopLoading();
    }
}}
```

Debugging, I've found out that the ScheduleServie.OnLoadComplete method is never called. First, the onCreate method is called, then onHandleIntent, and finally onDestroy. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Per the [IntentService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html) documentation:

> To use it, extend IntentService and implement onHandleIntent(Intent). IntentService will receive the Intents, launch a worker thread, and stop the service as appropriate.

This means that as soon as `handleIntent()` is finished, the service is stopped.

As `handleIntent()` is already on a background thread, you should use the synchronous methods to load data such as [ContentResolver.query()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html#query(android.net.Uri,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String)) rather than asynchronous methods such as `CursorLoader`. Make sure you close the `Cursor` returned by `query` before your method completes!